# Creating a unique list of names based on realized gains of an asset, extracted from the transactional history in google spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, unique, names

I am busy improving my template on google spreadsheet for an investment tracker.

**This is a description of what I try to achieve:**

- I have a transactional history sheet. This is present in the "History" sheet. In this sheet there is a list of every transaction ever made. I want to know the history of all realized gains. The realized gains can be calculated easily. It is simply the price you bought the asset for minus the price you sold it for!
- I wish to create a list of unique names of the assets that have been realized in the sheet "Calculations (2)" in cell AR 3.

**What I have tried so far:**

```
=unique(filter(History!B3:B,History!B3:B<>"Cash",ISERROR(MATCH(History!B3:B,Positions!A3:A,0))))
```

This formula looks in the history sheet in the column "B" where I write wether an asset has been "bought" or "sold" and it selects everything except "Cash". Then, it filters out all the currently owned assets by going to the sheet "Position" and excluding the names in column A (which are the ones I currently own).

**The problem:**

If you have realized an asset in the past but also currently own the asset, then the name will not be listed in cell AR3.

What is your advice. Haven't been able to figure it out on my own

**Link to tracker**: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QYq1u_vUcEjLrwktvoECQRsXfngnSfFXPnF56Al5zq8/edit?usp=sharing

Many thanks in advance!!

Comment: If you have transactions in the past, how is the formula meant to figure them out?

Comment: What do you mean? The formula is also meant to find a list of the transactions in the past.

Comment: I don't understand when you say "If you have realized an asset in the past but also currently own the asset, then the name will not be listed in cell AR3." Maybe you can share a simpler spreadsheet to highlight the specific problem you are having?

Comment: So what I meant to say was the following:

Let's say in the transactional history you have an asset which you bought 1x and you sold 1x. In this case, since you don't own the asset, it won't come up in the position tab and the formula I posted works fine. If you re-bought an asset after selling it (e.g. 2x buy and 1x sell) then it will show up in the positions tab, therefore, it will be removed from the unique list with the current formula. However, I solved my own question. Thanks for trying to help! See the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to find an answer to my own question. I did the following:

1. Create a column with a list of all unique assets with this formula:

   =unique(filter(History!B3:B,History!B3:B<>"Cash"))
2. Create a second column with a condition which is true, if an asset had a "sell" in the transaction history

   =IF(AR3 = "", "", IF(COUNTIFS(History!$C$3:$C,"Sell", History!$B$3:$B, AR3) > 0, "true", "false"))
3. Create a third column and filter the unique list of names if the condition is "true"

   =unique(filter(AR3:AR,AS3:AS = "true"))

Good luck for anyone else looking at a similar problem!